# How to check if a child element exists in parent in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I have a component structure as follows:

```
const Parent = (props) => {
  return <div>{props.children}</div>;
};

const Child1 = (props) => {
  return <h2>child 1</h2>;
};

const Child2 = (props) => {
  return <h2>child 2</h2>;
};
```

And I create an instance as follows:

```
const node = <Parent>
  <Child1 />
  <Child2 />
</Parent>
```

Now, as I am exposing this to outside world, users might forget to pass `<Child1 />` or `<Child2 />` in the parent. I want to detect this in the parent and then render something else based on if `<Child2 />` was passed or not.

What I tried: I have made use of the context API to have some communication between parent and child. I am looking for something simpler than this.

Something like this: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/next/packages/mui-lab/src/TimelineItem/TimelineItem.js#L69

Comment: If you're expecting a set amount of very specific components, why not pass them as separate props instead of using `children`? It would be very tricky to check it like that, whilst having a prop of `renderChildOne` or something like that would make it way easier to check

Comment: That will definitely be easier. But having an XML like syntax feels a bit more natural to me. So, was trying to see if there is some easy way to do this without using context-api.

Comment: Well, JSX is not exactly XML or HTML like, it's more of a syntactic sugar for function calls. So if you expect a constant amount of components, it's better to pass them as props. You'll see that a lot in libraries like Material UI, for example their `Autocomplete` component expects a prop called `renderInput`, instead of checking whether one of the children contains an input. So that's definitely the better pattern.

Comment: I am actually trying to something like Material UI. You can check this timeline component: https://material-ui.com/components/timeline/#opposite-content. Here, the TimelineOppositeContent is optional. And this is how they check if user has passed "TimelineOppositeContent" or not: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/next/packages/mui-lab/src/TimelineItem/TimelineItem.js#L69

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If only the number of children is important then:

```
  const count = React.Children.count(children);
```

To check specific components:

```
   let child1Exists = false;
let child2Exists = false;
    for (const key in props.children){
       const componentName = props.children[key].type.name
        
       switch(componentName){
         "Child1":
           child1Exists = true;
           break;
         "Child2":
           child2Exists = true;
           break;
         default: break;
        }  
    }
   
    if(child1exists && child2Exists){
      // All good!
    }
```

Comment: Hey. I tried this on a sandbox. It shows that the displayName is undefined. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-vdpvl?file=/index.js

Comment: Sorry, it should be .name... i updated my answer

Comment: This is helpful. Thanks. I wonder if this will still work when we bundle our code for deploying on PROD.

Comment: Use `let` to declare `child1Exists` and `child2Exists`; right now you'll get errors because you're setting new values on `const`s. Also, use `break;` under each `case`. Right now they are falling through, so if `componentName` is `"Child1"`, `child1Exists` and `child2Exists` will both be true.

Comment: Valid points @HereticMonkey. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

Its better to make this logic composable using higher order components.

This is the HOC. you can reuse it anywhere.

```
function withExpectedChildren(Component, expectedChildren = []) {
  return function Wrapped(props) {
    const hasAllExpectedChildren = expectedChildren.every((expectedChild) =>
      [props.children].flat().find((child) => child.type === expectedChild)
    );
    return hasAllExpectedChildren ? <Component {...props} /> : props.fallback;
  };
}
```

Wrap Parent component with the above HOC

```
const WrappedParent = withExpectedChildren(
  Parent,
  [Child1, Child2]
);
```

Render the composed component.
It renders fallback, if any child misses.

```
<WrappedParent fallback={<h2>you missed a child</h2>}>
   <Child1 />
   <Child2 />
</WrappedParent>
```

You can see the working fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/nqbL8g1m/

This is the idea, you shall modify it for your requirements